# Jetpack Compose countdown in Singleton Repository?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Singleton Repository:

```
class MyRepository @Inject constructor() {

    init {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            startTimer()
        }
    }

    var timer = 60 * 60 * 1000

    suspend fun startTimer() {
        while (timer != 0) {
            delay(1000)
            timer -= 1000
        }
    }
}
```

I want to start a timer in `init`, which runs automatically, regadless of the current screen.
And when I use this `MyRepository` again, I want to get the timers actual (elapsed) value, and show it on the screen realtime...
How can I create an observable Int value (`timer`), which runs independently from my screens / composables?

So I have `A`, `B` and `C` screens in this order.
`A` and `C` screen uses this `MyRepository` singleton. I want to show on `A` and `C` screens the actual value of the timer, and it needs to run in the background even during the `B` screen. When I push the `C` screen after `B`, I need to show the timer value again, with the elapsed time.

Comment: Except the fact that you should (almost) never use `GlobalScope`, the code seems fine to me. Is it not working? Do screens `A` and `C` get the same instance of this repository or different ones? As per your use case, you need to provide same instance to all the screens.